# Secondary Clustered DTC will not work when Primary goes offline - SQL Server Issues

Tags: sql-server, msdtc

I've been working on setting up clustered environment with a two new DTC roles, DTC1 and DTC2. I set up DTC1 which allows both clustered VM's and SQL Server Instances to function correctly. However, when I disable DTC1, DTC2 will remain online but no DTC transactions will work. I'm actually going through this issue with a Microsoft tech right now (without much luck). Both DTC services are set up with similar configurations. Anyone here have an idea as to what might be going on?

Here's my setup,

One clustered environment Two DTC Roles Two Separate ISCSI disks, one for each role Two VM's (same configuration) Two SQL Server Instances, on on each VM

Networking configuration is allowed, everything looks to be set up properly.